# Plugin allowing users to add articles to a library

Tags: plugins, library

We are currently redesigning our site (currently on Joomla) to a new Wordpress platform and I'm concerned I'm going to lose an important feature.

I have a membership based site and one of the features I wish to provide is for members to be able to maintain their own library of favourite articles from our article list. We have over 1000 articles online so this feature would allow members to save their favourites for easy access.

I've tried looking for document and library plugins but can't seem to find anything appropriate.

Does anyone know of a plugin that would do this effectively? Any other ideas??

Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: I would suggest you rephrase this to a technical howto question rather than a plugin shopping/recommendations question ( which would mean your question getting closed ), especially since the implementation of such a feature is simple

Comment: People with more than 1000 reputation don't seem very friendly to newcomers in this StackExchange.
's/of a/how to write a' and we've got a perfectly valid technical howto question.

Answer (score 0):

To keep track of each user's favourite articles you could store the post IDs of the articles in the $wpdb->usermeta table with a simple plugin.

Such a plugin would use the [add_user_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta), [get_user_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) and [delete_user_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_user_meta) functions to store and retrieve the IDs to/from the database.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll see if my developer can follow that. It's all chinese to me. Thanks